# Mouse hover events not working in the header of the TableView

Tags: qt, qml, tableview

Similar question is asked here

[How to get Clicked or Pressed event on QML TableView header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418541/how-to-get-clicked-or-pressed-event-on-qml-tableview-header/52421591#52421591)

I want to highlight the header when hovered over. But the behavior in `headerDelegate` is weird.

```
headerDelegate: Rectangle {
    height:30
    MouseArea{
        hoverEnabled: true
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressed: {
            console.debug("This will not be printed")
        }

        onEntered: {
            console.debug("Will print on pressed event")
        }

        onExited: {
            console.debug("Will print on released event")
        }
    }
}
```

Hovering over will not trigger any events at all.

Comment: The C++ tag is unnecessary in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover and other states are handled by the `styleData` component in the header delegate.

If you want to know when the hover changes, connect the different signals (`onPressed`, `onContainsMouseChanged`, etc.) of `styleData` to a function.

For example:

```
headerDelegate: Rectangle {
        height:30
        color: "red"
        Connections {
            target: styleData
            onPressedChanged: {
                console.debug("PRESSED:  "+ styleData.column + " " + styleData.pressed)
            }

            onContainsMouseChanged: {
                if (styleData.containsMouse)
                    console.debug("The mouse is hover the header of column " + styleData.column)
                else
                    console.debug("The mouse is leaving the header of column " + styleData.column)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well in ```headerDelegate```. I would like to use this method in ```rowDelegate``` also. But ```onContainsMouseChanged``` is not working inside ```rowDelegate```

Comment: Managing events in ```rowDelegate``` is discussed here.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56684357/tableview-how-to-get-hovered-row-without-loosing-styledata-selected

I wonder whether I can use the ```Connections``` method